# MySQL Database Restore error

Tags: mysql, database-restore

Getting the following error:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 530: MySQL server has gone away
```

Which I get after running the following from the MySQL (5.1.53-community) command line:

```
CREATE DATABASE restoredb;
```

then this from the Windows 7 system command line:

```
mysql -u root -p restoredb < "C:\restoredb.sql"
```

I've tried another database restore using another file and the MySQL restore command works fine.

Questions, feedback, requests -- just comment, thanks!!

Comment: It means you lost your connection to the server. Perhaps you left the connection open too long without sending anything and it timed out. Perhaps you tried to send a query that was so large it exceeded the timeout or maximum query size limit. Check MySQL's error log for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your my.ini (Win) or my.cnf (Linux)

If running as a service, put under [mysqld]

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=32M
```

Comment: @ed209: +1 thanks for posting, so "Put this in your my.ini" -- what is "this"? Meaning the code provided only appears to be for "If running as a service, put under" -- thanks!

Comment: Worked, only issue I ran into was related to Windows 7, which I posted posted as a question, then answer here: http://serverfault.com/questions/240246/attempted-to-edit-mysql-service-config-and-getting-access-denied