# Attempted to edit MySQL service config and getting "Access Denied"

Tags: mysql, configuration

As a follow-up to this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/240032/mysql-database-restore-error), I'm attempting to edit the "my.ini" config file for the MySQL service. I've stopped the service, opened the file, made the edit, and attempt to save it -- at which point I get an error saying "Access Denied". On Windows 7.

Questions, feedback, suggestions -- just comment, thanks!!

Comment: This is the exact problem i am facing today. :) what a coincidence today is 25 Feb as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In Windows 7,**

1. Right click on NotePad, and select "Run as Administrator"
2. Then from NotePad open the MySQL my.ini file
3. Make edits as needed, and save